# how does addbefore method work in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I am looking at the source code of LinkedHashMap and the addBefore method makes me confused a lot:

```
private void addBefore(Entry<K,V> existingEntry) {
            after  = existingEntry;
            before = existingEntry.before;
            before.after = this;
            after.before = this;
}
```

This method is invoked in createEntry method:

```
void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
        HashMap.Entry<K,V> old = table[bucketIndex];
        Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, old);
        table[bucketIndex] = e;
        e.addBefore(header);
        size++;
}
```

It is obvious that the parameter passed into addBefore method is always the header entry, so that **after** variable in addBefore method is always the header entry. Additionally, the header node is never changed.

My question is how does addBefore method work to form a doubly linked list?

Comment: It isn't clear to me how `this` is having its own `after` and `before` pointers assigned.  I think if you could explain that, then you would have the answer to your question.

Comment: Draw a few diagrams and it makes sense. If you want to insert before a `Node`, you have know the `Node` and the `Node` in front of it to insert inbetween them. `existingEntry` is the `Node` you want to add the new `Node` before. So find the `Node` before `existingEntry`. This `Node` is `existingEntry.before`. Now link the new `Node` to the end of the 'Node' before the addBefore `Node and to the beginning of the addBefore `Node`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson You're explanation is missing a few things; this may be where the OP is getting confused.

Comment: Just check these diagrams: http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/insertion-in-doubly-linked-list

Comment: I agree @TimBiegeleisen. I think a diagram would be nice to explain this.

Answer (score 2):

If you notice, each entry in LinkedHashMap has two pointers, *before and after*.

```
static class Entry<K,V> extends HashMap.Node<K,V> {
    Entry<K,V> before, after;
    Entry(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
        super(hash, key, value, next);
    }
}
```

I'll go line by line:

```
HashMap.Entry<K,V> old = table[bucketIndex];
Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, old);
table[bucketIndex] = e;
```

These 3 lines just find the first entry for *bucketindex* in the hashmap and adds the new node at the starting of the list for this bucket. So the old parameter passed here basically becomes next pointer for the inserted node.

The 4th line calls addBefore method in which header is passed as a reference.

`after = existingEntry` → Here existingEntry is header, and after is basically **this.after**, so effectively it makes the after pointer of new node to point to header.

`before = existingEntry.before;` → Again this makes the before pointer of the new node to point to **header's before** which is the last element in the list (it's a circular doubly linked list).

`before.after = this;` → This makes the after pointer of last node in list (because before of new node now points to last node in list) to point to the new node that we're inserting.

`after.before = this;` → This now changes the before pointer for header. Header's before must be changed because the last node in the list is now the new node that we're inserting, and this statement effectively does that.

So, a linkedhashmap maintains a **circular doubly linked list** for maintaining insertion order/access order (controlled by accessOrder parameter). I hope this helps you out.